# Unable to Associate?

Tags: support, user-accounts, association

Hi,

I'm trying to associate my SO, SU and Meta SO accounts. A few days back I had no problem associating SO and SU, but now that I'm trying to do the same with Meta SO, I get the following:

> Can't Associate This Account
>
> We found differing IP addresses
>   between sites for this association
>   request - please return to Meta Stack
>   Overflow and try again.

Not sure what's causing this, is it the fact that I log in from different locations (home and work) at different times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error says:

> We found differing IP addresses between sites for this association request

And you reveal:

> is it the fact that I log in from different locations (home and work) at different times?

Conclusion: **Yes.**

Comment: Ok thanks for making me look like a fool :P Worked fine when I tried associating the MetaSO account at home.

Answer (score 1):

If your IP address differs by too much between HTTP requests, we can't allow the association. This should only happen if your IP is shifting by a *lot* between HTTP requests.